# Ruby PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So for background, I just got a new computer and put Xubuntu 13.04 on it, then proceeded to put on RVM, Ruby, and Rails.  I've slowly been adding libs as I run into problems, but can't find the solution to this one.

When running `rake db:migrate`, I get the following output:

```
rake db:migraterake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/erik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I **think** I've made the common edits to the pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

and database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: stevenagy
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: localhost
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: stevenagy
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: localhost
  password:
production:
  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: stevenagy
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: localhost
  password:
```

Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: You didn't set a password,so the error.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `password` directive in your `database.yml` entries, but your `pg_hba.conf` requires `md5` password authentication. Specify a password for your connections, use an authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` that doesn't require a password, [or put the passwords in the `~/.pgpass` file if you don't want them in revision control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: I get the same output if I put "trust" for each entry in the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: @user3358307 Then you forgot to `pg_ctl reload` or `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` because if there are no `md5` entries you *can't* get that message.